# How to clear the Input/output buffer when when execute gud-run in emacs？

Tags: emacs, gdb

[image]

I use gdb in emacs. What I want is that the contents in the input/output buffer will be cleared when I execute gud-run.

I'm a new guy, who can tell me how to realize that?

Thanks in advance!